# PHP 7.3 Warning count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php

I get this message warning even when the array is not empty, I don't understand why because I checking fisrt if it is an array before to do the count

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($res_remind_att) && is_array($res_remind_att))
{   
    if(count($res_remind_att > 0))
    {...}
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($res_remind_att)`  and see what type it is.

Comment: Yes i did it is an array with one value

Comment: Ok, your braces are incorrect. It should be `(count($res_remind_att) > 0)`

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect.
Try writing it like this

```
if(isset($res_remind_att) && is_array($res_remind_att))
{   
    if(count($res_remind_att) > 0)
    {
    //here your code...
    }
}
```